# Does Cricket require a bowler's shoulders be at a certain level? Or just the arm to be straight?

Tags: cricket

I can't seem to find a definitive answer, but it seems like Cricket only requires the arm to completely straight when bowled and it cannot be underarm. This opens up the possibility of someone bowling a "submarine pitch" as It's essentially just sidearm while bent at the waist so that the shoulders line up with the arm. All you would need is your arm to be completely straight. You'd also be able to more accurately bowl a seam ball and achieve more spin being closer to the ground.

Is this legal? Or is there a law that I've overlooked governing this?

Answer (score 1):

Law 24.3 states: "A ball is fairly delivered in respect to the arm if, once the bowler's arm has reached the level of the shoulder in the delivery swing, the elbow joint is not straightened partially or completely from that point until the ball has left the hand.

Comment: Yes, but would it be within the realm of unfair play if your shoulders were not level when the ball was bowled?

Comment: No. The Laws define what is unfair play, and they say nothing about the shoulders being level.